# How to set the welcome page in a spring MVC application other than WEB-INF folder?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, servlets

Here is the directory structure of my application.I have highlighted the welcome.jsp file(which is available in WEB-INF folder directly).

[image]

***I want to keep the default page/welcome page(page which need to open when try to run the app in server) for this application inside WEB-INF/view folder.What configuration i need to change for this sothat it can run .Please help ! ,thanks in advance.***

web.xml:

```
<!DOCTYPE web-app PUBLIC
 "-//Sun Microsystems, Inc.//DTD Web Application 2.3//EN"
 "http://java.sun.com/dtd/web-app_2_3.dtd" >

<web-app>
  <display-name>Archetype Created Web Application</display-name>
  
  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>subu</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
  </servlet>
  
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>subu</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
  
  
  <welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>welcome.jsp</welcome-file>
  </welcome-file-list>
  
</web-app>
```

dispatcher servlet i.e.

subu-servlet.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:ctx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-2.5.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-2.5.xsd ">
    
    
    <ctx:annotation-config></ctx:annotation-config>
    <ctx:component-scan base-package="com.controller"></ctx:component-scan>
    
     
     
     
    <bean id="viewResolver"
      class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.UrlBasedViewResolver">
    <property name="viewClass" value="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView"/>
    <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/view/"/>
    <property name="suffix" value=".jsp"/>
</bean>
    
    
</beans>
```

welcome.jsp :

```
<html>
<h1>Welcome page !!!!!!!!</h1>
<body>


<form action="add">
    <input type="text" name="t1"><br>
    <input type="text" name="t2"><br>
    <input type="submit">
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

AddController.java file under com.controller package:

```
package com.controller;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView;

import com.service.AddService;

@Controller
public class AddController
{
    
    @RequestMapping("/add")
    public ModelAndView add(HttpServletRequest request,HttpServletResponse res)
    {
        int i=Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("t1"));
        int j=Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("t2"));
        
        AddService as=new AddService();
        int k=as.add(i, j);
        
        ModelAndView mv=new ModelAndView();//need to specify 2 things,view name and what data you want to pass
    
        mv.setViewName("display");
        mv.addObject("result",k);
        
        return mv;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2):

1. Please add `<mvc:view-controller path="/" view-name="yourviewPage"/>` to the application config file. Then the ROOT will resolve to the yourviewPage view.

You can change the path value to the welcomepath

2. Then add

```
<bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
    <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/views/"/>
    <property name="suffix" value=".jsp"/>
</bean>
```

to the applicationconfig file. This will resolve the view to `/WEB-INF/view/yourviewPage.jsp`.

Comment: after using ```<mvc:view-controller path="/" view-name="welcome"/>``` got the welcome page as welcome.jsp . but from the welcome page,while trying to click submit button ,control is not going to the controller.Showing ```Sep 04, 2020 6:08:42 PM org.springframework.web.servlet.PageNotFound noHandlerFound
WARNING: No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/Demo_SpringMVC/add] in DispatcherServlet with name 'subu'
```any help